# How to create an infinite in Python

Tags: python

I created a version of the nim game, but it goes below zero.  The way I have it set up the computer always takes the same amount as me, but if the count is at 4 and I take 3 out, it will be 1 for the computer's turn.  Then the computer takes 3 out and it shows as -2.  So how would I tell the program to always keep the count above or equal to zero?  Also does anyone know how to make it so the computer doesn't always input the same amount as me?

Here is my code.

```
import random
Stones = random.randint(15, 30)
User = 0
YourTurn = True

print("This is a game where players take turns taking stones from a pile of stones. The player who 
takes the last stone loses.")
print("The current stone count is:", Stones)

while True:
     while YourTurn == True and Stones > 0:
    User = int(input("How many stones do you want to remove?"))
    if User == 1:
        Stones -= 1
        print("You removed 1 stone! The current stone count is:", Stones)
        YourTurn = not True            
    elif User == 2:
        Stones -= 2
        print("You removed 2 stone! The current stone count is:", Stones)    
        YourTurn = not True                       
    elif User == 3:
        Stones -= 3
        YourTurn = not True
        print("You removed 3 stone! The current stone count is:", Stones)
    else:
        print("You can only remove a maximum of 3 stones.")

    while YourTurn == False and Stones > 0:
        AI = random.randint(1, 3)
        if AI == 1:
            Stones -= 1
            print("The A.I removed 1 stone! The current stone count is:", Stones)
            YourTurn = not False
        elif AI == 2:
            Stones -= 2
            print("The A.I removed 2 stone! The current stone count is:", Stones)
            YourTurn = not False
        elif AI == 3:
            Stones -= 3
            print("The A.I removed 3 stone! The current stone count is:", Stones)
            YourTurn = not False

if Stones <= 0:
    if YourTurn == True:
        print("The A.I took the last stone it lost. You won the game!")
        break
    elif YourTurn == False:
        print("You took the last stone you lost. The A.I won the game!")
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the number of stones the AI can get in its turn from `random.randint(1, 3)` to `random.randint(1, min(3, Stones))` so that it can't get any more stones than the number of remaining ones.

```
import random
Stones = random.randint(15, 30)
User = 0
YourTurn = True

print("This is a game where players take turns taking stones from a pile of stones. The player who takes the last stone loses.")
print("The current stone count is:", Stones)

while True:
    while YourTurn == True and Stones > 0:
        User = int(input("How many stones do you want to remove?"))

        if User > Stones:
            print("Your can't remove more than the number of remaining stones.")
            continue

        if User == 1:
            Stones -= 1
            print("You removed 1 stone! The current stone count is:", Stones)
            YourTurn = not True            
        elif User == 2:
            Stones -= 2
            print("You removed 2 stone! The current stone count is:", Stones)    
            YourTurn = not True                       
        elif User == 3:
            Stones -= 3
            YourTurn = not True
            print("You removed 3 stone! The current stone count is:", Stones)
        else:
            print("You can only remove a maximum of 3 stones.")

    while YourTurn == False and Stones > 0:
        AI = random.randint(1, min(3, Stones))
        if AI == 1:
            Stones -= 1
            print("The A.I removed 1 stone! The current stone count is:", Stones)
            YourTurn = not False
        elif AI == 2:
            Stones -= 2
            print("The A.I removed 2 stone! The current stone count is:", Stones)
            YourTurn = not False
        elif AI == 3:
            Stones -= 3
            print("The A.I removed 3 stone! The current stone count is:", Stones)
            YourTurn = not False

    if Stones <= 0:
        if YourTurn == True:
            print("The A.I took the last stone it lost. You won the game!")
            break
        elif YourTurn == False:
            print("You took the last stone you lost. The A.I won the game!")
            break
```

Comment: Thanks, would you also know how to make it so the computer doesn't always take away the same amount of stones as me?

Comment: The computer in the given code takes a random number of stones since you use the `random.randint` function in `AI = random.randint(1, min(3, Stones))`. So it doesn't always take the same amount of stones as the player. Did you mean that you want the number of stones taken away by the computer have to always be different from the player's?

Comment: Did you remove the `break` line under the printing win message line? If so then you should put it back because it is used to exit the `while True:` loop

Comment: Thank you I got it now, yeah I just took out the break for some reason.

Comment: But what would I do if the player inputs too big of a number which turns the final count negative?

Comment: You probably need to add a check for the number of stones the player input. If it is larger than the remaining stones, prompt the user to enter again. I've updated my answer with the check implemented.

Comment: What would I need to do so it randomly chooses who goes first.

Comment: Instead `YourTurn = True`, you can set it randomly by changing it to `YourTurn = bool(random.getrandbits(1))`